# Reduce the use of ctx when working in Canvas for creating shapes

Tags: javascript

With ES6 or ES5, is there a way to avoid continuous typing ctx over and over and over again when managing image properties and methods?   Meaning if I have the following code:

```
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Filled triangle
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(25, 25);
    ctx.lineTo(105, 25);
    ctx.lineTo(25, 105);
    ctx.fill();

    // Stroked triangle
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(125, 125);
    ctx.lineTo(125, 45);
    ctx.lineTo(45, 125);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```

Can we do something like...

```
ctx = { //parent name here only once

    //then all properties or methods associated to it here...
}
```

Comment: You could use `with` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with  but please head the warning on using it.  But for this particular code seems a reasonable use case.

Comment: `with` may help in this case, and I didn't know about it. but what alternatives would we have to it if it potentially gets out of hand on larger scale conditions?  I just cant see myself typing the same name space value, over and over and over and over within a creative canvas design project.  It makes no sense in my brain.

Comment: If I had to come up with a good reason to use `with`, your example would be a good one.  So there is nothing majorly wrong in using it in small doses.   IOW: if it's obvious to somebody else reading your code, that `moveTo / lineTo` belong to the `ctx` var, you should be OK.  But just be aware of the Ambiguity issue that link points out.  When I say over use, I also don't mean as in the number of lines, but the places you use it, eg.  a bad design is when you have `with` within another `with`, within anther `with` etc etc.

Comment: ahhh now I have a bit more clarity in what you mean by abusing it.  many many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of using `with`

But be careful of over using it, Javascript context can get confusing as it is, over use of `with` makes this worse.

But for something simple like this, I can't see an issue.

```js
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    with (ctx) {
      // Filled triangle
      beginPath();
      moveTo(25, 25);
      lineTo(105, 25);
      lineTo(25, 105);
      fill();

      // Stroked triangle
      beginPath();
      moveTo(125, 125);
      lineTo(125, 45);
      lineTo(45, 125);
      closePath();
      stroke();
    }
  }
}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```